# Improper display of splitter screens in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have a requirement where the screen orientation is always landscape and we need to have two splitter screens in a view.

I have used following code to render two splitter screens. The layout is such that splitViewController1 takes 60% of view and splitViewController2 takes 40% of view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:background]];

    [splitViewController1.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,150, 0.6 * width, height)];
    splitViewController1.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [splitViewController1 setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:150.0] forKey:@"_masterColumnWidth"];
    [self.view addSubview:splitViewController1.view];

    [splitViewController2.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.6 * width,150, 0.4 * width, height)];
    splitViewController2.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [splitViewController2 setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:150.0] forKey:@"_masterColumnWidth"];
    [self.view addSubview:splitViewController2.view];
}
```

Now the issue which am facing is that in the main view, the detailed view of splitter screen is not scaled to the frame width, but its overlapping the other splitter view.

To provide more insight I would like to mention that detailed view of each splitter control doesn't respect the frame boundaries which am specifying.

All views in my project are set to landscape oriented.

Any suggestions for the above situation ?

Also I would like to know if there is any other method to decrease the rootview controller's width of splitter screen.

Answer (score 0):

After going through your question, i am not sure what actually is causing the problem , but i can suggest you to have a look at [MGSplitViewController](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController) as i myself have used it before and it is really helpful.

Comment: I saw that project but from that I could not make where am making mistake. I think am doing some wrong either in the frame creation or rendering both splitter views in screen. But am nowhere to solve the issue